# Nested loop over list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I've got a list of dataframes that I want filtered depending on the values in one column that all three of them have. I want to split all three dataframes into three each; one sub-dataframe for each value in that one column. So I want to make 9 dataframes out of 3.
I've tried:

```
df_list=[df_a,df_b,df_c]
for df_tmp in df_list:
    for i, g in df_tmp.groupby('COLUMN'):
        globals()[str(df_tmp) + str(i)] =  g
```

But I get super weird results. Can someone help me fix that code?
Thanks!

Comment: Please share what you have coded so that the community can analyze it and provide suggestions.

Comment: What does `str(df_tmp)` give you for these dataframes?

Comment: Literally that's what I've done, not sure what else I can add for context... the dataframes are quite simple, just a couple of columns (but a lot of lines), and one column is "COLUMN" (obv this is just an example).

Comment: str(df_tmp) gives me essentially one of the dataframes, if I'm seeing this correctly. With it, I was trying to give the output dataframes names. But clearly it's not working as I intended it to.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list with dictionaries: One dictionary for each of the original dataframes, each one containing one dataframe referenced with the unique name from 'COLUMN'.

```
tables = [{'df_' + name: df[df['COLUMN'] == name].copy() for name in df['COLUMN'].unique()} for df in df_list]
```

So, for example, you can call `tables[0]` to get the three dataframes derivated from `df_a`. Or `tables[0]['df_foo']` to get the table from `df_a` with all the rows with the value 'foo' in the column 'COLUMNS'.

Or, if you want to use a dictionary to have all the df associated with keys instead of indexes in a list:

```
tables = {'df_' + str(i): {'df_' + name: df_list[i][df_list[i]['COLUMN'] == name].copy() for name in df_list[i]['COLUMN'].unique()} for i in range(len(df_list))}
```

and then you can all them as `tables['df_0']['df_foo']`.

You can of course create a list of names and use it to assing the keys:

```
df_names = ['df_a', 'df_b', 'df_c']
tables = {'df_' + name: {'df_' + name: df_list[i][df_list[i]['COLUMN'] == name].copy() for name in df_list[i]['COLUMN'].unique()} for item in df_names}
```

And now you do `tables['df_a']['df_foo']`.

Let's say you choose to use one of the dictionaries and want to apply a single operation to all the dataframes, for example, let's say that each dataframe has a column called `'price'` and you want to apply a function called `get_discount()`, then

```
for key1 in tables:   # top level corresponding to [df_a,df_b,df_c]
    for key2 in tables[key]:   # bottom level corresponding to each filtered df
        tables[key1][key2]['prices'] = tables[key1][key2]['prices'].apply(get_discount)
```

Comment: You haven't explained how you plan to assign names to the new dataframes. So, this is just the way that comes to my mind right now. Of course, you may want to adapt it to get  each df associated with an unique name instead of indexes in a list. Maybe a dictionary with dictionaries...

Comment: Oh, I just realized now how you were trying to assign names to the dataframes! I haven't tried it, but I don't think is aesthetically right (or even programmatically, but who cares!) to use a loop to populate the global namespace.

Comment: Hi, thank you, that's great. It does work. But I'm not sure what to do with that "tables" format in the end. I can access it the way you suggest but is there any way to have all the 9 dataframes saved as dataframes so that I can further work on them using lists and loops again? Thanks!

Comment: *They are dataframes*!! What you want is to have each dataframe associated to a single name, and right now they are inside some other structure, like a list or a dictionary. You can of course do `df_foo = tables[0]['df_foo']`. You could create a bunch of empty DFs and then use a loop to assign the values to each name. But you can't ask python to choose the names for you.

Comment: I get that, and thank you. My problem is that I have quite a few dataframes (I said "9" just for illustrative purposes) and I need to do further work on them. So I can call them individually as you suggested either through the index or through the dict. I can also rename them individually. But I'd like to work on all of them at once, perhaps through a DF list and a for loop. And I don't know how to reference them now, since there's two levels to the structure. 
My instinct would be: for key in tables: df_'key'=df[key] or something.

Comment: I just edited it with how to write the loop.

Comment: Also, consider that if you need to work on all of them together, maybe it wasn't a good idea to split them in the first place. You can do practically anything to grouped data.